# Google Cloud CDN not accepting signed cookies via browser

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cors, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-cdn

Google Cloud CDN is set with a backend bucket which is configured and working for signed cookies when called via `curl`.

I have the Cloud-CDN-Cookie set correctly in the browser, but when calling the CDN, the Request Headers  don't include it (No Cookie header present).

When called in the browser, with a fetch like this:

```
fetch('https://<bucket-ip>/test/test.png', {
  method: 'GET',
  credentials: 'include',
 })
```

The browser returns the following error:

> Access to fetch at 'https:///test/test.png' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

Does Google CDN need to return this 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header for it to work? I wasn't able to find anywhere how to add this header in the response from Google CDN.

Comment: What domain is the cookie getting written on versus the delivery? Usually, when the cookie isn't being sent, it is because the domain it is written against is different. Could it be that the set-cookie domain and the request are different? CORS header control is more browser control and not overtly a Cloud CDN thing. You can have Cloud CDN set CORS headers via the Application Load Balancer, but Cloud CDN unto itself doesn't enforce CORS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to make the cdn send the response headers I needed.

In this section:

[image]

You can set the headers you need like this:
[image]